# Python - populate nested dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Starting form a list:

```
user1 = ['alternative', 'rock', 'pop']
```

I can populate a `dictionary` with the number of appearences of each item.

```
u1={}
for tag in user1:
    u1[tag]=1
print u1
```

and get: `{'alternative': 1, 'pop': 1, 'rock': 1}`

likewise, for:

```
user2 = ['indie', 'rock', 'chamber pop']
```

the same:

```
    u2={}
    for tag in user2:
        u2[tag]=1
    print u2
```

and get: `{'indie': 1, 'chamber pop': 1, 'rock': 1}`, and so on.

but lets say I want to populate this `dict` in the same fashion:

```
users = {
         u1:{}, 
         u2:{},
         u3:{},
         ...
         ...
        }
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have users and lists already stored to a dictionary. Then you could iterate over all key value pairs within [*dictionary comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to convert the list to `dict` with counts:

```
from collections import Counter

users = {
    'u1': ['alternative', 'rock', 'pop'],
    'u2': ['indie', 'rock', 'chamber pop'],
    'u3': ['indie', 'rock', 'alternative', 'rock']
}

res = {k: Counter(v) for k, v in users.items()}
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'u1': Counter({'alternative': 1, 'pop': 1, 'rock': 1}), 
 'u3': Counter({'rock': 2, 'indie': 1, 'alternative': 1}), 
 'u2': Counter({'indie': 1, 'chamber pop': 1, 'rock': 1})}
```

To break above a bit `users.items()` returns an iterable of `(key, value)` tuples:

```
>>> list(users.items())
[('u2', ['indie', 'rock', 'chamber pop']), ('u1', ['alternative', 'rock', 'pop']), ('u3', ['indie', 'rock', 'alternative', 'rock'])]
```

Then dict comprehension turns the list to `dict` containing the counts:

```
>>> Counter(['indie', 'rock', 'chamber pop'])
Counter({'rock': 1, 'indie': 1, 'chamber pop': 1})
```

Finally for each the user name and resulting `Counter` are added the to the result `dict`.

Comment: You can wrap the `Counter(v)` with `dict`: `dict(Counter(v))` if you must have a plain `dict` and not a `Counter`.

Comment: @DanD. Good addition, typically it doesn't matter though since `Counter` is a `dict` and in behaves like a one in almost all scenarios.

Comment: thanks. this technique is more useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` is a good option. But according to this question we can use more simple option. Check this out.

```
users = {
    'u1': ['alternative', 'rock', 'pop'],
    'u2': ['indie', 'rock', 'chamber pop'],
}

res = {}
for user in users.items():          # return each key:value pair as tuple
    res[user[0]] = {}               # first element of tuple used as key in `res` for each list
    for tag in user[1]:             # return each element of list 
        res[user[0]][tag] = 1       # assign value as 1 of each element.

print res
```

Output:

```
{'u1': {'alternative': 1, 'pop': 1, 'rock': 1}, 'u2': {'indie': 1, 'chamber pop': 1, 'rock': 1}}
```

Comment: simpler indeed. i would just use 'genre' or 'tag' instead of 'list_user', to make it more readable.